# how to spawn unity player with filled game object fields in unity 2d

Tags: unity-game-engine

The game is working correctly and there arent any other issues apart from the fact that the public fields from the players scripts that are supposed to be filled with game objects from the scene arent filled and im not sure how to do that.

heres an example from one of the scripts: [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Smo9L.png)

and heres what it should look like: [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A36Z4.png)

the joystick area from the second image is from the scene, not an asset: [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N5OZm.png)

here is the code im using:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class MovePlayer : MonoBehaviour
{

public MovementJoystick movementJoystick;
public int playerSpeed;
private Rigidbody2D rb;
bool facingRight = true;
public Animator animator;
public float interval;

// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    playerSpeed = 7;
    interval = 10;
}

// Update is called once per frame
void FixedUpdate()
{
    if (movementJoystick.joystickVec.y != 0)
    {
        rb.velocity = new Vector2(movementJoystick.joystickVec.x * playerSpeed, movementJoystick.joystickVec.y * playerSpeed);
        animator.SetFloat("speed", Mathf.Abs(movementJoystick.joystickVec.x));
    }
    else
    {
        rb.velocity = Vector2.zero;
        animator.SetFloat("speed", Mathf.Abs(0));
    }

    if (movementJoystick.joystickVec.x < 0 && !facingRight)
    {
        Flip();
    }
    if (movementJoystick.joystickVec.x > 0 && facingRight)
    {
        Flip();
    }
}

void Update()
{
    if (playerSpeed == 14 && interval > 0)
    {
        interval -= Time.deltaTime;
    }

    else
    {
        playerSpeed = 7;
        interval = 10;
    }
}

void Flip()
{
    transform.Rotate(0f, 180f, 0f);

    facingRight = !facingRight;
}

public void SpeedControl(int newplayerSpeed)
{
    playerSpeed = newplayerSpeed;
}
}


using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;

public class MovementJoystick : MonoBehaviour
{

public GameObject joystick;
public GameObject joystickBG;
public Vector2 joystickVec;
private Vector2 joystickTouchPos;
private Vector2 joystickOriginalPos;
private float joystickRadius;

// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    joystickOriginalPos = joystickBG.transform.position;
    joystickRadius = joystickBG.GetComponent<RectTransform>().sizeDelta.y / 2;
}

public void PointerDown()
{
    joystick.transform.position = Input.mousePosition;
    joystickBG.transform.position = Input.mousePosition;
    joystickTouchPos = Input.mousePosition;
}

public void Drag(BaseEventData baseEventData)
{
    PointerEventData pointerEventData = baseEventData as PointerEventData;
    Vector2 dragPos = pointerEventData.position;
    joystickVec = (dragPos - joystickTouchPos).normalized;

    float joystickDist = Vector2.Distance(dragPos, joystickTouchPos);

    if (joystickDist < joystickRadius)
    {
        joystick.transform.position = joystickTouchPos + joystickVec * joystickDist;
    }

    else
    {
        joystick.transform.position = joystickTouchPos + joystickVec * joystickRadius;
    }
}

public void PointerUp()
{
    joystickVec = Vector2.zero;
    joystick.transform.position = joystickOriginalPos;
    joystickBG.transform.position = joystickOriginalPos;
}
}
```

this is how to instantiate the player using photon servers (what i am using)

```
    public GameObject playerToSpawn;
        PhotonNetwork.Instantiate(playerToSpawn.name, spawnPoint.position, Quaternion.identity);
```

Edit: I have tried to delete this question as it is a duplicate but it will not allow it.

Comment: I'm quite perplexed. If you want to set a reference to a public field, what's stopping you from doing that from inspector or code? Or the issue is, that you somehow lose reference when hitting play button or changing scenes? Above that, if everything is working fine, what do you need that field for then?

Comment: If you make a prefab you cannot reference scene items on the prefab because they don’t exist. In short you need to find them on creation

Comment: Yes I don't know how to code that, I don't have alot of knowledge on code for me to be able to do this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create (or use an already existing) "Controller" script to do so,
createa  variable to save the reference to that object in "Controller" and once you instantiate prefab, use GetComponent to access the script attached to that object, then set reference to the attached script from controller.

```
public class MainController : MonoBehaviour
{
    // drag and drop that object here to save reference
    [SerializeField] private MovementJoystick movementJoystick;
    [SerializeField] private GameObject movePlayerPrefab;

    void Start()
    {
        var movePlayerObject = Instantiate(movePlayerPrefab);
        var movePlayerScript = movePlayerObject.GetComponent<MovePlayer>();
        // once you have reference to that newly instantiated object set saved reference with method
        movePlayerScript.SetJoystick(movementJoystick);
    }
}
```

```
public class MovePlayer : Monobehaviour
{
    private MovementJoystick movementJoystick;

    public void SetJoystick(MovementJoystick movementJoystick)
    {
        this.movementJoystick = movementJoystick;
    }
}
```

Comment: in your answer @asd worker you ask me to "set saved reference with method", but im not sure how to do that and what you mean by that. ive edited the question to show the scripts im using to move the player

Comment: Thanks for sharing your code @SSam202020 , but that was not necessary for this situation. 
" im not sure how to do that" - When you add "MainCotnroller" component to a `GameObject` there will be empty fields, drag and drop `GameObject` that has `MovementJoystick ` as a component in the field named `movementJoystick`

Comment: Im still quite confused on how to implement the code into my scripts as i dont have any experience in programming. can you please put the code into my scripts because when i tried it i got a bunch of errors. Also i am using photon servers so i edited the original post to show how i instantiated the player as from your code snippets it looked like you wanted to instantiate but the way you did it wouldnt work on the photon server.

Comment: can you answer my comment?